# How to loop X amount of times in RPG free without creating variables?

Tags: loops, recursion, procedure, rpgle

I have piece of old code that I am trying to convert

Very simple, just loops 10 times

```
C                   DO        10
C* code 
C                   ENDDO
```

In order to use `for` loop in free syntax, a variable needs to be created. For example:

```
  FOR I = 1 TO 10;
    // code
  ENDFOR;
```

Any way to accomplish this without the need of creating a new variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but in RPG IV this is not necessarily as much of a problem. In RPG IV you can use procedures, and procedures can have local variables. RPG 400 and before only allowed global variables. However, if you are using subroutines in your RPG IV programs, you still have to use global variables.

You aren't still using subroutines are you?

Here is the syntax difference:

Subroutines in free:

```
exsr mysubroutine;

...

begsr mysubroutine;

   ...

endsr;
```

what it looks like with minimal sub-procedures;

```
myProcedure();

...

dcl-proc myProcedure;

   ...

end-proc;
```

You strictly don't need the `()` after the procedure name if you are not passing parameters, but I do this anyway because it clues me in that it is a procedure and not a random variable or other name sitting alone on a line, or even in an expression.

Advantages of procedures?

1. You can declare local variables for those loops.
2. You can still use all the global variables that your subroutines use.
3. You can pass parameters.
4. You can return a value and use the procedure in an expression.
5. Procedures can be called recursively.

Gotchas?

1. You can still use all the globals that your subroutines use.
2. You can't call a subroutine from within a procedure unless it is defined within the procedure.
3. You can't call a subroutine defined inside a procedure from outside that procedure.

Gotchas #2 & #3 mean that it might be best to convert all of your subroutines to procedures. You can do that without any side effects.

Comment: This is a really great idea. I will try to use procedures going on forward. All the legacy code would be too big of a task for me to convert to procedures though

Comment: No doubt. I don't convert things either unless I have a reason to do so.